# Conjecture related to Lychrel numbers

Tags: number-theory, recreational-mathematics, palindrome

My conjecture is as follows:

Take any number. It will become a palindrome eventually through the same reversal process used for Lychrel numbers except if the term (first term is excluded) starts with 1, the 1 is disregarded.

For example:
196+691=887

887+788=1675 => 675

675+576=1251 => 251

251+152=403

403+304=707 is a palindrome.

Can anyone prove this or find a counterexample? Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 3):

The smallest counter-example is $10039547$, which gets into a cycle:

$$
\begin{array}{}
\color{red}{84632548} \\
69156196 \\
38321392 \\
67633775 \\
25367451 \\
40843803 \\
71678607 \\
42366224 \\
\color{red}{84632548} \\
\end{array}
$$
Found by exhaustive brute-force search.

Comment: does this mean all numbers less than $10039547$ end in a palindrome?

Comment: @miracle173 Yes. Only after $10^7$ we get (a lot of) examples that start cycling.

Comment: @miracle173 I found cycles in other number bases, but I can't find them for all number bases. (See [linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4321213/318073) question if interested.)

Comment: maybe something to calculate for you https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4333686/how-to-transform-a-monomial