# How to transform a monomial

Tags: polynomials

Let's start with the monomial $x$. The goal is to get to a constant term by differentiation and multiplication with $2x$. For some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, you have an exact number of steps $k = 2n+1$ you have to take to get there.

For example, for $n = 0$ (3 steps), we have the following paths:
$$
x \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 2x \rightarrow 2 \\
x \rightarrow 2x^2 \rightarrow 4x \rightarrow 4
$$

Similarly, for $n = 2$ (7 steps), we have these possible paths:
$$
x \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 2x \rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 4x \rightarrow 4 \rightarrow 8x \rightarrow 8 \\
x \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 2x \rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 4x \rightarrow 8x^2 \rightarrow 16x \rightarrow 16 \\
x \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 2x \rightarrow 4x^2 \rightarrow 8x \rightarrow 8 \rightarrow 16x \rightarrow 16 \\
x \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 2x \rightarrow 4x^2 \rightarrow 8x \rightarrow 16x^2 \rightarrow 32x \rightarrow 32 \\
x \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 2x \rightarrow 4x^2 \rightarrow 8x^3 \rightarrow 24x^2 \rightarrow 48x \rightarrow 48 \\
x \rightarrow 2x^2 \rightarrow 4x \rightarrow 4 \rightarrow 8x \rightarrow 8 \rightarrow 16x \rightarrow 16 \\
x \rightarrow 2x^2 \rightarrow 4x \rightarrow 4 \rightarrow 8x \rightarrow 16x^2 \rightarrow 32x \rightarrow 32 \\
x \rightarrow 2x^2 \rightarrow 4x \rightarrow 8x^2 \rightarrow 16x \rightarrow 16 \rightarrow 32x \rightarrow 32 \\
x \rightarrow 2x^2 \rightarrow 4x \rightarrow 8x^2 \rightarrow 16x \rightarrow 32x^2 \rightarrow 64x \rightarrow 64 \\
x \rightarrow 2x^2 \rightarrow 4x \rightarrow 8x^2 \rightarrow 16x^3 \rightarrow 48x^2 \rightarrow 96x \rightarrow 96 \\
x \rightarrow 2x^2 \rightarrow 4x^3 \rightarrow 12x^2 \rightarrow 24x \rightarrow 24 \rightarrow 48x \rightarrow 48 \\
x \rightarrow 2x^2 \rightarrow 4x^3 \rightarrow 12x^2 \rightarrow 24x \rightarrow 48x^2 \rightarrow 96x \rightarrow 96 \\
x \rightarrow 2x^2 \rightarrow 4x^3 \rightarrow 12x^2 \rightarrow 24x^3 \rightarrow 72x^2 \rightarrow 144x \rightarrow 144 \\
x \rightarrow 2x^2 \rightarrow 4x^3 \rightarrow 8x^4 \rightarrow 32x^3 \rightarrow 96x^2 \rightarrow 192x \rightarrow 192
$$

Now I want to know: What is the sum of the results? In the first case, it would be $2+4 = 6$. In the second, it is
$$
8+16+16+32+48+16+32+32+64+96+48+96+144+192 = 840
$$

Through my testing, it seems like the answer is probably $(2n+3)!/(n+1)!$ (it definitely fits with the examples, because $3!/1! = 6/1 = 6$ and $7!/3! = 5040/6 = 840$). But I cannot figure out how to prove it. Is there a nice way?

Comment: Could you give an example with $n=1$?

Comment: I don't understand. In your first derivation, you arrive at a constant term straight away ($1$) but the process doesn't terminate

Comment: @FShrike yes, but for n=0 we want 4*0+3 = 3 steps

Comment: @MJD added a further example. I hope it becomes a little bit clearer now.

Comment: I see now.  You have pairs $\langle a, b\rangle$, and in one step you can change $\langle a, b\rangle$ to either $\langle 2a, b+1\rangle$ or $\langle ab, b-1\rangle$.  For a given $k$, you want to find paths from $\langle 1, 1\rangle$ to $\langle c, 0\rangle$ and you want the sum of all the terminal $c$ values for each possible path of $k$ steps, for some given $k$ which happens to be of the form $4n+3$.

Comment: @MJD Right, that seems like a better way to formulate it :D

Comment: @fynsta why do you exclude k=5, 3 differentiations and 2 multiplications? E.g. $$x \rightarrow 2x^2 \rightarrow 4x^3 \rightarrow 12x ^2\rightarrow 24x\rightarrow24\\x \rightarrow 2x^2 \rightarrow 4x \rightarrow8x^2 \rightarrow16x \rightarrow16\\\ldots$$

Comment: @miracle173 This problem is an extension of another problem where that had to be excluded. But feel free to enlarge the scope of the question to k=4n+1 (I guess the results are the same?)
I edited the question